# Google web designer - Ads Expandable - Animate while expanding (i.e slide down)

Tags: ads, double-click, google-web-designer

I am using [google web designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/) to create expandable ads but when I click the banner it immediately shows the expanded version.

Is it possible to animate the banner when expanding like the jQuery [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) function.

I think if I manipulate the function that causes the expanding I can achieve this but will it be against the google/double click ads rules?

I have been googling on this a lot but couldn't find anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: will that be possible to show us on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an expandable, GWD automatically creates 2 pages, a tap area on the first page, and an event (on the event panel) with the animation between the two pages.

Click on the event, and you will be able to change the transition animation with the one you selected.

[image]

> Screenshot is from GWD version 1.5.4.0113 & might be different in
>   future.

If you, on the other hand, are creating an engagement ads. No transition needs to be created between the two pages. The doubleclick runtime will add all the necessary transition (including the 2 seconds rollover progress bar) once you uploaded in studio (or dcm, dbm)

Comment: Thanks but the slide animation is not working properly when viewing in double click preview section. I have created a separate questions for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674975/expandable-ad-slide-animation-starting-half-way-through-in-double-click-previe), Take a look may be you know what I did wrong.